# Cannot read property 'column' of undefined

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

```
$('.user-data thead th').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
    this.dataTable.column(2).search(this.value).draw(); });
```

i want to search column wise but this code give me column error like column is undefined

Comment: All that error tells you is that `this.dataTable` is not defined, you will need to either provide more code or check to see if `this.dataTable` has been properly defined or if you defined it by another name

Comment: this.dataTable = $("#user-data").DataTable({
            dom: 'l<"#status">frtip',
.........
});

Comment: in this code :
var thiscontext = this;
if i'll change like this
$('.user-data thead th').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
                        thisContext.dataTable.column(2).search( this.value ).draw();
                    });  
then error like:
thisContext.dataTable.column(...).search(...).draw is not a function

Comment: can you please help it's very urgent and already take 2 day

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first `this` is not in the scope you think. The second `this` is in the right scope.

Assign `this` to a local variable:

```
const that = this;

$('.user-data thead th').unbind().bind('keyup', function(){
    that.dataTable.column(2).search(this.value).draw(); 
});
```

Comment: if i use this then error:--
that.dataTable.column(...).search(...).draw is not a function

Comment: What is the output of `that.dataTable.column(2).search(this.value)` in the console? Is `search()` returning non-empty value?

Comment: i'm not able to search when i'm input then error on console is:-
that.dataTable.column(...).search(...).draw is not a function

Comment: You just need to add `console.log(that.dataTable.column(2).search(this.value))` before you call the `draw()` method.

Comment: console is blank

Comment: It means, the `search` returns an empty value. Try logging `that.dataTable`, `that.dataTable.column(2)` and `this.value` to console to see if everything works as expected.

Comment: then what can i do for this?

Comment: now i'm use this:-
$('#user-data ').on('keyup change', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
                            console.log('called=>', thisContext.dataTable.column(2).search( this.value ) + this.value);       
                    });

result of this console is :---[object Object]aa

now what can i do then search functionality execute??

Comment: Try logging without converting to string: `console.log('called =>', thisContext.dataTable.column(2).search( this.value ), this.value)` Concatenating with `+` converts object to string. That's why you see `[object Object]`

Comment: yes, i know but when i was using JSON.stringify then i got error:-

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
so i'm not able to see result

Answer (score 0):

Have you, by any means checked out [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/col_filter) example?

As for your code, I may see couple mistakes:

- `this` inside event listener corresponds to HTML element (not even jQuery object), so it doesn't have property `dataTable` which you refer to;
- `value` attribute is not available either, so your search is, basically, looking for `undefined`, in fact, I might assume you were trying to do `.val()`;
- since you're using `.user-data` as a parent node inside your selector, you should be aware that search will be performed upon each table on the same page having the same class, that could seem rather awkward, I'd recommend to use unique id instead;
- another reason why it may not actually work is because your table contents (including `thead`) are generated dynamically, so you cannot attach event listener to it right away, and must use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/);

Considering the above, if example snippet, which I referred above, would not work for you, for some reason, I would change your code for something, like:

```
$('#tableid thead th').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
    dataTable.column(2).search($(this).val()).draw(); });
```

Which will not necessarily fix the problem, as I cannot see  the rest of the context.
You may find working **DEMO** [over here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqQPjO?editors=1010).

Comment: thankyou for your last demo example. but  it is working only for static data whenerver i use ajax and give option of serverside it is not working can you help in this ??

Comment: var dataTable = $('#user-data').DataTable({
            dom:'l<"#status">frtip',
              serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: environment.apiUrl + '/manager/users',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataFilter: (d) => {
                        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(d);
                        return JSON.stringify(json.error.data);
                    }
                },
                pagination: true,
                sortable: true,
                order: [0],           
        columns: [           ]
          });

Comment: and also whenerver i user  serverSide: true in this option od datatable then i got only    one data. and seraching also not working

Comment: Plug-in works just fine with data, sourced via AJAX. However, when you use option `serverSide: true`, searching is supposed to be performed **server-side**, so client-side external filters `$.fn.DataTable.ext.search` are not in effect, which makes sense, considering large amount of data.